# how to change kubelet working dir to somewhere else

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

kubernetes 1.7.x

kubelet store some data in /var/lib/kubelet, how can I change it to somewhere else ?

Because my /var is every small.

Answer (score 10):

if your `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` is loading environment from `/etc/sysconfig/kubelet`, as does mine, you can update it to include your extra args.

```
# /etc/sysconfig/kubelet
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--root-dir=/data/k8s/kubelet
```

Entire `10-kubeadm.conf`, for reference:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

Answer (score 8):

Ok. I figured it out.
On centos.

/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf

you can add

```
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=$KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS --root-dir=/data/k8s/kubelet"
```

then

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Comment: Did you have to reinstall Kubernetes or you managed to keep your current install?

Comment: @goo No need to reinstall.

Comment: Thanks, @xren. I Applied this to a cluster in RHEL and it's working fine!

Answer (score 8):

If it should go fast and without any problems, just create a simlink to a other location with sufficent space.

As kubelet's root-directory is located at `/var/lib/kubelet`, copy the `/var/lib/kubelet` content to the new desired location, for example `/data/k8s/kubelet` and after rename the `/var/lib/kubelet` directory to `kubelet-bup` for backup purpose.

Create a SymbolicLink from documentation:
`$ln -s /path/to/dir /path/to/symlink`

In this example, use:
`$ln -s /data/k8s/kubelet /var/lib/kubelet`

this should work immediatly, otherwise use

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04

for reference: https://devdojo.com/tutorials/what-is-a-symlink