# Not able to change Kubernetes Logs Directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to change kubelet logs directory location. For achieving same I have modified `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` file contents as follows(as mentioned in [how to change kubelet working dir to somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045943/how-to-change-kubelet-working-dir-to-somewhere-else))

```
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--root-dir=/D/kubelet-files/ --log-dir=/D/kubelet-logs/"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS
```

After this I executed commands :

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Even I restarted `kubeadm`. But still logs directory location is not changed and it goes on writing to default `/var/lib/kubelet` directory . I am using `Kubernetes version: v1.11.2`. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried on some machines of mine on GCloud with `v1.11.2`
and I noticed the same your problem.

The parameter `--log-dir` in kubelet seems to have no effect.

It is worth opening an issue in kubelet project.