# Is there any way to change default folder of kubelet pods overlay?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, overlay

In my kubernetes cluster, master nodes have often DiskPressure problem due to /var partition usage.
I noticed that the /var/lib/kubelet folder takes up a lot of space and I was going to change this folder as a kubelet overlay pointing to one in a larger partition.
I've already done this with docker and etcd, but I can't figure out how to do this change of kubelet pointing, has anyone done it yet?

Comment: which kubernetes version?

Comment: My k8s cluster version is v1.15.1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) of kubelet flags. In that page search for `root-dir`

if you are using CentOs system then follow below:

Step 1.a: edit (for older k8s version) /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf as shown over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46065250/4451944) 
Step 1.b: edit (for newer k8s version) /etc/sysconfig/kubelet as shown over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53228571/4451944)
Step 2: 
`systemctl daemon-reload`
`systemctl restart kubelet`

Explanation: `--root-dir` flag is what you need to specify your new directory. This flag needs to mentioned as an *extra args* in the kubelet drop-in file but the structure of the drop-in file changed in the new kubelet versions as shown in step 1.a and 1.b.