# How to increase ephemeral storage size in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, storage, on-disk, ephemeral-storage

**What are good ways to provide big "scratch" storage to Kubernetes jobs/deployments that require a lot of disk?**

I read about [ephemeral volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/ephemeral-volumes/) and it seems that the ideal thing for the case is to mount `emptyDir` volumes. My problem is that `emptyDir` volumes are mounted under `/var` on the host by default (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525081/does-kubernetes-mount-an-emtpydir-volume-on-the-host/46526490#46526490)), and I have hard limits on the size of the `/var` partition, therefore I cannot get enough space to use as "scratch" space for my expensive on-disk pods.

**Is there a way to change the default location of where ephemeral storage is mounted?**

I couldn't find it anywhere.

I cannot find any useful options in the [`emptyDir` spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#emptydirvolumesource-v1-core).

I wouldn't want to use persistent volume claims because I don't need to persist anything.

Nor I want to mount empty directories in big partitions outside of `/var` from the host as `hostPath` volumes, because that would be abusing `hostPath`s which have a different semantics than what I need. (Although that would work, but it seems kind of a hack).

**Are there other solutions that one could employ?**

Comment: Are you running k8s on a cloud or datacenter environment?

Comment: It's on premise in my case

Comment: If you can control the node provisioning, then you could have an alternative to the `/var` folder. Sadly this seems only configurable via the kubelet `rootDirectory` and there is no dedicated config for emptyDir.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut any link to how to change `rootDirectory`?

Comment: @MichelePiccolini depends on how you provision it, but it seems to be just an cmdline argument when running the kubelet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045943/how-to-change-kubelet-working-dir-to-somewhere-else